# How to play a sound when my index.html changes

Tags: html

I upload every 1 minute my index.html to an ftp. Sometimes the index stays the same, sometimes it is changes a little. I am looking for a way to play a sound when my index.html changes. 
I refresh the page automatically every 20 seconds  . I want to play a sound if it has changed, Maybe it can read the size of the file and if it is diferent to play a sound? –

Is it possible?

Thank you for your time and for sharing your skills.

Comment: What do you mean *When my index.html changes* ??

Comment: I upload every 1 minute my index to an ftp. Sometimes the index stays the same. sometimes it is changed.small changes..

Comment: Basically, it's not possible to do what you're asking without some pretty intense work arounds..after your browser loads `index.html` it doesn't ever reload or re-read it until either you force a reload or the user refreshes the page, aka, the browser is unaware the index.html file changed.

Comment: So you want refresh content/index.html  automatically after some period time ? or you want to refresh a  part of index.html ?

Comment: I refresh the page automatically every 20 seconds <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20"> . I want to play a sound if it has changed, Maybe it can read the size of the file and if it is diferent to play a sound?

Comment: so with `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">` your browser will reload, but it has **no** way to keep track of the file from the previous load. It loads the html it as a blank slate. Like I said, you would need to do some work arounds like keep a secondary file perhaps that stores the last upload date time, then maybe have JS read the secondary file and do some logic, or use some kind of server side language to do something similar.

Comment: If the file changes, add a sound file to the HTML that automatically plays when refreshed. if it doesn't change, remove the sound file and nothing will play.

Comment: @GiannisChristopoulos I have added an answer. Maybe this is pretty easy way for you.

Comment: Thank you guys for all that help you gave me..All was very good approaches.. i decide to use the easiest way timgavin gave me :D thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't think this is all that complicated. If index.html has changed, simply add an audio file that automatically plays. If it has not changed, remove the audio file and no sound is made.

#### file has changed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<audio autoplay>
  <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

    your content here...

</body>
</html>
```

#### file has not changed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    your content here...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without considering all possible edge cases, this is actually fairly straight forward. You just need to make use of `localStorage`.

The idea being, that on document load, you compute the current size of the document and then compare this to a value you've stashed in `localStorage`.

A better solution would save a size and hash of the file - this way, you could still detect when data was changed yet the file size didn't change.

I've simply set the background colour to green.

```
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    if (hasDocChanged())
        document.body.style = "background-color: #A0FFA0";
}

function hasDocChanged()
{
    let result = false;
    var curSize = document.body.innerHTML.length + document.head.innerHTML.length;
    var lastSize = localStorage['lastDocSize'];
    if (curSize != lastSize)
        result = true;
    localStorage['lastDocSize'] = curSize;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Run on snippet. You can use this  [Live On Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/sLcx3ebn/1/) . U can use this onload in your meta tag also like this-

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20" onload='$.playSound("http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3724")'>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $.playSound('http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3724');
})
```

```html
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound/master/jquery.playSound.js'></script>
  
  <body onload='$.playSound("http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3724")'>
  <p>
    Please remember to remove .mp3 file extension.[Just a Reminder You can remove this]
  </p>
</body>
```